# Force garbage collection Azure Blobstorage after deletion container in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code to delete a container on Azure Blobstorage:

```
        public IActionResult DeleteDownloadLink(string container)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration["StorageConnectionString"];
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);

        _moduleRepository.DeleteDownloadLink(container);

            blobContainer.Delete();
            return RedirectToAction("ManageDownloadLinks", "Admin");
    }
```

This doesn't delete the container straight away, and I found the following in the documentation:

> When a blob is successfully deleted, it is immediately removed from
> the storage account’s index and is no longer accessible to clients.
> The blob’s data is later removed from the service during garbage
> collection.

However, I can still go to the link and download it. No error is returned. So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my delete code?
2. If nothing is wrong with the code, can I force garbage collection so the link is no longer accessible?

Comment: `However, I can still go to the link and download it` - Do you mean you can access the blob in a container even after that container has been deleted?

Comment: That is correct. At first I thought the delete failed but even if I put a try catch around it, it doesn't throw an error on deletion

Comment: It should not happen. Are you using an old URL for the blob? Can you check if the browser is not caching the data?

Comment: I save the url to the blob in the database, so I'm sure it's not an old URL, looking at the timestamp. It's also not cached data, I deleted the downloadlink, then deleted cache and then tried to download. Still works

Comment: That's weird. Your code looks ok to me. Can you try to access the blob in some other browser? Also please confirm that the container is indeed deleted. You can check for that in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

I create below sample to test, I can delete container successfully. The only difference between my code and yours is that there is no `_moduleRepository.DeleteDownloadLink(container);` this line of code.

#### 1. My first suggestion is that you can comment out this line and try again.

#### 2. Check your `StorageConnectionString`, make sure you delete correct container.

```
[HttpGet("blobtest")]
public async Task<string> DeleteDownloadLink(string container)
{
    var connectionString = "DefaultEn***indows.net";
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);

    if (await blobContainer.ExistsAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Created container {0}", blobContainer.Name);
        try
        {
            var a= blobContainer.Delete();
            return "delete successed";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "delete failed";
            throw;
        }
    }
    return "don't exist";
    //blobContainer.Delete();
    //return RedirectToAction("ManageDownloadLinks", "Admin");
}
```

Comment: That one line of code just deletes the downloadlink from the database, so it doesn't show up in the ui when listing all active links. StorageConnectionString should be OK since I can upload to it. Thanks though

Comment: @dgrs check again the connectionstring, don't mistake the strings used in production and development.

Comment: Was indeed the connectionstring...